# Oil rush from Software center on other platforms

Tags: software-center, crossplatform

I bought [Oil Rush](https://store.unigine.com/products/goods/oilrush/) from the Ubuntu software center not to long ago and I love the game. The thing is I also want to be able to play the game on my Windows box or my other Linux boxes not running Ubuntu.

Is there anyway I can download the versions for other platforms as if I had bought it at their store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try sending the developers an email asking about it add your proof of purchase and they will probably help you with the problem

Comment: After waiting a while for a response, they said it was not possible at this time.